# TCPDF Textfield issues with default value

Tags: php, forms, tcpdf

I'm trying to create a PDF file with a form. I'm using php and tcpdf.
The text fields need to be precisely positioned to fit the image in the background. 
Some of the text fields have default values (via the 'v' attribute).

The issue is that when I click the text field to edit the contents, the text moves a few pixels to the side (probably because of the border around the active input field). When the input loses focus, the text does not return to the original position.

I've tried to visualize the problem with these screenshots:

(note the text position relative to the line below)

[image: Problem examples]

My form default settings:

```
$pdf->setFormDefaultProp(array('lineWidth'=>1, 'borderStyle'=>'solid', 
'fillColor'=>array(), 'strokeColor'=>array(255, 128, 128)));
```

This is the code for the field:

```
$pdf->TextField('test', 47, 6, [], ['v' => 'test(12)'], 8, 13);
```

What I have tried so far:

- setting the `lineWidth` to `0`, but while the border is no longer visible, the text still moves.
- setting the `borderStyle` to `'none'`, same result.
- setting the `strokeColor` to `[]`, same result.

What I would like to do:

- set a padding to the default value (or otherwise influence its positioning)

or

- remove the border from the active form field (not just make it invisible)

I noticed the same behavior on the TCPDF example here: https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_014/

If you click into the address field, the text moves up and to the left.

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't solve the problem with PHP, I managed to find a viable workaround (at least for our project):

If I insert the default values via Javascript, the effect doesn't occur.

```
$js = "
var fields = {'field1':'test', 'field2':'test2'};
for (var fieldName in fields) {
    if (!fields.hasOwnProperty(fieldName)) continue;
    var field = getField(fieldName);
    if (field && field.value === '') {
        field.value = fields[fieldName];
    }
}
";
$this->pdf->IncludeJS($js);
```

This has the drawback, that if the user empties a field, the default value will be filled in again on next opening the file. This is no use case for our project, so it works for us, but keep it in mind!

So it's by no means perfect, but it helped us move on with our project. And maybe someone searching for this problem finds this helpful :)

If anyone finds an actual solution, I'd still be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to distinguish the first time a user opens the (blank) form, from when they re-open it after they saved it with the field emptied.

In the textfield, set the value (or default value) to 10 blanks. In your javascript, first check for 10 blanks, and if there, insert your default values.  If the field has anything but 10 blanks, don't insert defaults.  The user is unlikely to use exactly 10 blanks to clear a field.

But if that isn't robust enough, use another textfield that the user would never edit (like a version number).  Start with it empty, and insert the version number (or whatever) only after you have checked the field, and inserted your set of defaults.